# FTP over'd image files with transfer-type: ASCII; possible to revert?

Tags: ftp, conversion, file-transfer, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering corrupted files uploaded in wrong FTP mode](https://superuser.com/questions/195612/recovering-corrupted-files-uploaded-in-wrong-ftp-mode)
>   [undo effect of ASCII ftp transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/496949/undo-effect-of-ascii-ftp-transfer)

I've downloaded hundreds of files from a Drupal install using FileZilla. 
Mistakingly I forget to change the transfer type from `ASCII` to `Auto`.

How do I modify all these files so that they will be viewable correctly?

(I'm thinking a `sed`/`awk` command or similar)